# AWK script to print a single next word following a pattern match from Description field

Tags: awk

I have below CSV file:

```
CreateDate, First Name, Last Name, Description
2023/03/25, Makvala, Anima, Your orders are 6157 and total value is 854257
2023/03/26, Leobwin, Saturnus, Your orders are 72 and total value is 1575675
2023/03/25, Boadicea, Pradip, Your orders are 52116 and total value is 29344357
```

I want below output

```
Orders: 6157, Total Value: 854257
Orders: 72, Total Value: 1575675
Orders: 52116, Total Value: 29344357
```

I already looked for a couple of similar questions on StackOverflow, but they are extracting the word considering there is only 1 field and then separating using `orders are` , but I have multiple fields and I want to get the values from `Description` field.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: will *all* Descriptions have the same exact format of *`Your orders are #### and total value is ####`*; if not then please update the sample input to show other possible formats

Comment: Thans Mark. Yes all inputs are going to have same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Like this with [any `POSIX` awk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13):

```
awk -F, '
    NR>1{
        split($4, a, / +/)
        print "Orders:", a[5] ",", "Total Value:", a[10]
    }
' file
```

##### Output

```
Orders: 6157, Total value: 854257
Orders: 72, Total value: 1575675
Orders: 52116, Total value: 29344357
```

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
CreateDate, First Name, Last Name, Description
2023/03/25, Makvala, Anima, Your orders are 6157 and total value is 854257
2023/03/26, Leobwin, Saturnus, Your orders are 72 and total value is 1575675
2023/03/25, Boadicea, Pradip, Your orders are 52116 and total value is 29344357
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="Your orders are | and total value is "}NR>1{printf "Orders: %d, Total Value: %d\n",$2,$3}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Orders: 6157, Total Value: 854257
Orders: 72, Total Value: 1575675
Orders: 52116, Total Value: 29344357
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is `Your orders are`  OR `and total value is`, thus I get 3 fields: 1st is before Your orders..., 2nd is # of orders and 3rd is total value, then for each line after 1st (`NR>1`) I use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) to get output formatted as desired.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Also works with mawk 1.3.4, which I think is the default awk on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v FPAT=' [0-9]+' 'NF==2 {print "Orders:" $1 ", Total Value:" $2}' file.csv
```

With `FPAT` variable set to one space followed by one or more digits, the fields become your number of orders (first field) and the total value (second field). Everything else is ignored. Then, if there are two fields we print your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk

```bash
gawk '
    BEGIN { re = @/Your orders are ([0-9]+) and total value is ([0-9]+)/ }
    match($0, re, m) { printf "Orders: %s, Total Value: %s\n", m[1], m[2] }
'
```

[Strongly Typed Regexp Constants](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strong-Regexp-Constants.html)